# Cannot access image in dir in apache

Tags: php, apache

I have created two directories where i am storing profile pic. When i access these images by typing there url , it automatically converted to index.php
I am typing

```
http://192.168.1.147/Dropbox/control_panel/uploads/users_big/196.jpg
```

here 192.168.1.147 is my local network address
this address is automatically converted to

```
http://192.168.1.147/Dropbox/control_panel/uploads/users_big/index.php
```

i also have an image in uploads folder

```
http://192.168.1.147/Dropbox/control_panel/uploads/196.jpg
```

this image can be access easily.

This is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^notifications/?$ notifications.php
RewriteRule ^trash/?$ trash.php
RewriteRule ^Library/?$ library.php
RewriteRule ^docs/([\s\S\+]+)$ docs/checkfile.php
</IfModule>
```

**Additional Details**
After converting to index.php the page says that "This webpage has a redirect loop" and also there is no index.php file exists

Comment: Can you write your .htaccess ? or apache conf ?

Comment: No i mean , paste your htaccess here

Comment: We need your .htacces and if you're on linux post the output of :
`ls -l <path-to>Dropbox/control_panel/uploads/`

Comment: i have appended my .htaccess to my question above, but i think i have not written any code in it for this dir

Comment: Maybe it is cause of your apache/nginx conf. Can you put them out here ?

Comment: I have not changed anything like this in my apache conf file. This problem is same on my local server (xampp) and on webserver (vps). I think it is default settings on apache.